# Вывод информации из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста какая ошибка в этом коде, данные в mysql есть в этих таблицах, но не выводятся

```
    $password=$_POST['pass_auth'];
    $model = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM models WHERE password='$password'",$db);
    if (empty($model)) { echo ("Вы ввели неправильную информацию!");} else {    
    $resultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE model_id='$model'",$db); 
    $array = mysql_fetch_array($resultat);
    do
    {
    echo "<li>
<a href='uploads/".$array['url_big']."' class='lightbox-image' rel='prettyPhoto[group1]'>
<img src='uploads/".$array['url_small']."' alt='' style='opacity: 1;'>
<span></span></a>                                       </li>";
    }
    while($array = mysql_fetch_array($resultat));}
```

Comment: Больше информации, что за ошибка, где подключение к бд?

вижу уже ошибку номер рас.

    $resultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE model_id='$model'",$db); 

а как насчет 
 
     $array = mysql_fetch_array($model);
     $resultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE model_id='".$array['id']."'",$db);

Comment: Подключение к БД идет правильно

Comment: Ну тогда ответ в коментарие выше) вы сделали выбоку из базы но данные из массива не достали... и не привели код ошибки или запрос в чистом виде(сформированая php строка которая передается в базу) который не возвращает данные. из кода я заметил только эту ошибку, и она приведет к результату что ошибок явных не выводится(хотя не факт от настройки зависит) и информации нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все довольно тяжко. Разберем все по пунктам.
Во имя безопасности, не используйте просто пароль из POST, там может быть [sql-инъекция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Дабы обезопасить себя от таких вещей пишите следующее:

```
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass_auth']);
```

Вот в этой строчке:

```
 $model = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM models WHERE password='$password'",$db);
```

А вы смотрели что сохраняется после этого в $model? Посмотрите как-нибудь. В $model храниться информация о **запросе**, а не информация из БД. Чтобы ее получить, нужно сделать:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($model);
```

Чтобы проверить на то, имеется ли в базе пользователь с таким паролем, empty() не пойдет. Используйте

```
if(mysql_num_rows($model)>0) echo "Все хорошо";
```

Так, что еще... При условии, что все хорошо в запросе укажите не переменную $model, я уже объяснял почему, а элемент массива $result. Чтобы понять как он устроен print_r() в помощь. Вроде как все.

Comment: @Arc, если уж и говорить о "лекарстве" против sql-инъекций, то на сегодняшний день это не отдельные функции экранирования, а использование PDO или MySQLi

Comment: Да емое. Простите, это не к вам лично относиться, а к обществу программистов в целом. Если я использую mysql, а не mysqli, это означает ровно то, что мне так **удобно**. Я прекрасно знаю, что это такое, и когда совсем уж припрет и его окончательно удалят, перейду на mysqli.

Comment: @Arc, дык чего ж вы советуете экранирование? Если ТС его не использует, то это тоже может означать ровно то, что ему так удобно. А если уж припрет и какой-нибудь хацкер положит базу, тогда он и обратится к нам с просьбой разрулить проблему.

Comment: это был сопутствующий совет.

Comment: В моем комментарии - это так же не приказ...

Comment: Согласен, был не прав. Просто уже человек десять меня об этом просят. Прошу прощения.